# export XML -> Excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel, openxml, export-to-excel

I'm already generating an excel XML file (.xml) containing 2 worksheets.

issue #1:

the people downloading the XML file wouldn't know to open the file in Excel. (they'd complain.)

solution #1:

I rename the file to .XLS instead of .XML.

issue #2:

when opening the file in Excel i get the this error:

```
The file you are trying to open, ‘XXX.xls’ is in a different format than specified   by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.
```

Solution #2:

Convert the XML file to XLS file somehow.

so here's where i turn to you...

Goal:

they need to be able to open the file by double-clicking it.
i don't want to have to rebuild the excel file using some 3rd party library.

Ideas:

perhaps convert XML to xls using tools like the following:

```
http://npoi.codeplex.com/
http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/
```

I'd need some sample code of the simplest and LITEst way of achieving this.

any other ideas?

Comment: Look at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e315c516-2c2c-4870-a189-d47a5d7ffeb3&displaylang=en
Its a microsoft xml download that works with excel. Not sure if it provides everything you need as I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random thought: if you're generating XML for people to open with Excel, why not generate XSL (or maby XSLX) in the first place?

Comment: (i'm guessing you mean xls and xlsx)
A text based template is used for all other reports on the project.
I don't like that this would be the only report that uses a 3rd party dll in order to generate spreadsheets, simply because it has multiple worksheets.

Comment: OK, for XSL you'll need some kind of component. As for XSLX you don't necessary need any 3rd party component. Basically this is just some XML in a zip-file.

BTW: if you're running a web-app, you can create a HTML-table and mark the content-type of the page to application/excel and excel will be able to show the table as a spreadsheet.

Comment: I thing setting the content-type will not allow for multiple worksheets.
unless someone else states otherwise it seems that the zip file is the way to go.

Comment: you're right, you won't be able to do multiple worksheets with the solution is described.